# How can we copy an EVP_PKEY which includes RSA key?

Tags: c, openssl, x509, private-key

I found the function `EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters`, which can copy `EVP_PKEY`. 
But some documentations about this function says it can only be used for DSA/ECC algorithms.
The official documentation (from [openssl.org](http://www.openssl.org)) does not mention whether the function can be used for RSA EVP_PKEYs.

Another implementation for `EVP_PKEY` (that contains an RSA key) could be this:

```
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(RSAPrivateKey_dup(EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey)));
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't **really** need to duplicate the key, you can just increment its reference count, like this:

```
CRYPTO_add(&your_evp_pkey->references, 1, CRYPTO_LOCK_EVP_PKEY);
```

**Otherwise**, a similar (almost identical) approach to what you suggested would be the following:

```
int pkey_rsa_dup(EVP_PKEY *dst_pkey, EVP_PKEY *src_key) {
    // Validate underlying key type - Only allow a RSA key
    if (src_key->type != EVP_PKEY_RSA)
        return -1;

    RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(src_key); // Get the underlying RSA key
    RSA *dup_rsa = RSAPrivateKey_dup(rsa); // Duplicate the RSA key
    RSA_free(rsa); // Decrement reference count

    EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(dst_pkey, dup_rsa); // Set the underlying RSA key in dst_pkey
    // EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA also adjusts the other members in dst_pkey

    return 0;
}
```

<s>Reference: [Re: How to duplicate an EVP_PKEY](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg17614.html)</s> -> As @X-Istence says below, the `RSA_dup` method suggested in this reference thread doesn't exist in OpenSSL (at least until the date of this update).

Comment: RSA_dup doesn't exist anywhere in the OpenSSL source code. Specifically in that same email thread, the follow-up by the same poster says as much: http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg17617.html

Comment: `dst_pkey` leaks

Comment: @Orient you're right. Thanks! I had a bogus/unnecessary allocation for `dst_pkey`. The passed argument must reference a pre-allocated pkey.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenSSL 1.0.0d, `EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters` should work. However, judging from the implementation, it just seems to copy the public parameters:

```
static int pkey_rsa_copy(EVP_PKEY_CTX *dst, EVP_PKEY_CTX *src) {
    RSA_PKEY_CTX *dctx, *sctx;
    if (!pkey_rsa_init(dst))
        return 0;
    sctx = src->data;
    dctx = dst->data;
    dctx->nbits = sctx->nbits;
    if (sctx->pub_exp) {
        dctx->pub_exp = BN_dup(sctx->pub_exp);
        if (!dctx->pub_exp)
            return 0;
    }
    dctx->pad_mode = sctx->pad_mode;
    dctx->md = sctx->md;
    return 1;
}
```

Apart from jweyrich's solution, another simple method is to first `i2d_RSAPrivateKey` your RSA key then `d2i_RSAPrivateKey` it again - there's your copy :)

Comment: Instead of i2d/d2i methods that require you to know what the underlying type is, use PEM_write_PrivateKey/PEM_read_PrivateKey instead. This way RSA, DH, EC, and DSA private keys are all copied without explicitly knowing the underlying type.

Comment: I'll use i2d/d2i for another purpose. This answer really saved me days and days of work... Now, i'll fit to tomorrow's deadline.... Thanks a lot, man