# Invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘RSA’ {aka ‘rsa_st’}

Tags: c++, openssl, copy, rsa, sizeof

I'm trying to make own C++ library of openssl RSA algorithm, but I've stuck at creating copy contructor of my class, because I cannot copy instance of RSA.

My class looks like this.

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
class Rsa
{
    protected:
    RSA *rsaptr;
    .
    .
    .
    public:
    Rsa(const Rsa &rsa); //copy constructor
}
```

And my implementation of copy contructor:

```
Rsa::Rsa(const Rsa &rsa)
{
    this->rsaptr = RSA_new();
    memcpy(this->rsaptr, rsa.rsaptr, sizeof(*(rsa.rsaptr)));
}
```

But `sizeof` doesn't work because of incomplete type. It shows this error:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘RSA’ {aka ‘rsa_st’}
```

How can I get size of RSA instance, or am I missing some includes?

Comment: RSA* rsaptr points to an instance hidden from public access, you can't do memcpy.

Comment: So how can I copy RSA instance, is there some function like RSA_copy(RSA*)?

Comment: You can copy the private key, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449443/how-can-we-copy-an-evp-pkey-which-includes-rsa-key.

Comment: Or is it better to use std::shared_ptr<RSA> rsaptr?